# Encryption that works equally for iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone, encryption

I am trying to write an encryption class that will allow iPhone to send encrypted text to Android and vice versa. While this is quite straightforward in Android (following code)

```
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
private static final int RANDOM_KEY_SIZE = 128;

// Encrypts string and encode in Base64
public static String encrypt( String password, String data ) throws Exception 
{
    byte[] secretKey = generateKey( password.getBytes() );
    byte[] clear = data.getBytes();

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( clear );
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString( encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT );

    return encryptedString;
}

// Decrypts string encoded in Base64
public static String decrypt( String password, String encryptedData ) throws Exception 
{
    byte[] secretKey = generateKey( password.getBytes() );

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

    byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode( encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT );
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( encrypted );

    return new String( decrypted );
}

public static byte[] generateKey( byte[] seed ) throws Exception
{
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance( RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM );
    secureRandom.setSeed( seed );
    keyGenerator.init( RANDOM_KEY_SIZE, secureRandom );
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    return secretKey.getEncoded();
}
}
```

I have seen tens of answers on similar topics but did not get a really working piece of code for iOS that gives identical results. Most of the pieces of code don't even compile properly. Does somebody has a real working piece of code for that?

Answer (score 2):

See [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) on iOS, and [JNCryptor](http://cryptonode.org/jncryptor/) for Java. They implement the same file format. It correctly handles AES-CBC-256 with a random IV, PBKDF2 generated passwords with random salt, and validated HMAC for data authentication and integrity.

Comment: I have downloaded that and will check it. Thanks.